# Control BlackBerry from PC

Tags: remote, remote-control, blackberry

I've got a BlackBerry Storm running OS 5.0 and I'm looking to control it from my Windows (and/or Mac) as the screen button it broken! I only plan to use this for development until we buy another device but I was wondering if it was possible to do this and if so, does anyone have any links :)

The control can be over the wire, I don't want to restrict it to Bluetooth or VNC but will do if it's the only way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somewhat costly, but you could check out Impatica viaDock. I downloaded the demo and it works fine.

Comment: Yea I got that working! It's not amazing but does the job!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem you can control your BlackBerry from your computer.
BlackBerry useful sites- downloads are free.

Main BlackBerry download site:
http://www.blackberrydownload.net/

BlackBerry Help Doc's: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/17860/BlackBerry_Desktop_Software-User_Guide--1236316-0725104952-001-6.0.0-US.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I was after. I can connect the BB to the PC fine. I have all BB software downloaded already. All I want to do is control the phone from windows and I don't see anything about that in those docs (I've previously scanned through them)!

Comment: Also, first link is a dead one!

Comment: sorry about the link,it did work and i have found it used on other sites[which are now dead],i have not been able to find a way to run b.berry from computer-chat sites have commented that nokia suite has this feature and b.berry should but nobody seemed to know how to do it.Sorry it does not look as if b.berry can be run from your computer as everything seems to be phone side controled.

Comment: viaDock works in a kinda VNC like way. Worth checking out but not worth buying!

Answer (score 0):

Try SOTI Pocket Controller-Pro for BlackBerry which will work via USB and WiFi. You will also see your device skin which is very cool.

Link to the product is on  www.soti.net

Let me know if you have any issues getting the product.